# Using testcafe API client side only

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

We have a server testing framework for our application already and are interested in using the client side event playing functionality of testcafe such as typeText() and click() at the client side only.
So basically I'm looking for a primer how to include the various client side testcafe .js files (such as testcafe/lib/client/driver/index.js, testcafe/lib/client/automation/index.js etc) in our pages in order and how to call the automation events client side only.
(I'm aware that this leaves the intended scope of testcafe, but may be someone else did already do what we are after)

Comment: > and are interested in using the client side event playing functionality of testcafe such as typeText() and click() at the client side only.

Could you please clarify why the standard way of executing TestCafe actions isn't suitable for you?

Comment: @mlosev we have a native shell (Qt framework hosting a Qtwebview) comparable to electron where we do all the JS injecting stuff testcafe does. As an example: we can run our web apps remotely via ssh and this native shell/webproxy allows to run the web app on the desktop without any web server inbetween). Therefore we don't need all the browser shell handling, the proxy and so forth. The pure JS event injecting part of testcafe is the interesting part for us.

Answer (score 0):

The client-side TestCafe API depends on the server-side part and cannot work correctly for all cases without it. There are no plans to introduce such functionality. Please use TestCafe actions in a regular way.